# Which Sentence Does Not Belong Here?

Tags: american-english, terminology, sentence, paragraphs

I am trying to figure out the sentence that does not belong to this paragraph.

*The researchers developed three criteria for the test subjects. The test subjects needed to be women because the drug was marketed to them. Also, they needed to be between the ages of 21 and 35. Having subjects during the prime childbearing years would eliminate age related causes for drug failure. Another cause of drug failure might be incorrect use. Finally, all subjects need to have abstained from illegal drug use. Prior drug use can interfere with the drug's efficacy*

I thought it would be the second sentence, but apparently this is wrong. Which one would it be and why then?

Comment: The sentence "*Another cause of drug failure might be incorrect use.*" does not belong, because it is not a "*criterion the researchers developed for the test subjects*", nor an explanation nor justification of any such criterion.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence *"Another cause of drug failure might be incorrect use."* should be removed, because it is not in context.

There are three criteria that are being discussed, and other causes of drug failure are irrelevant to the three criteria that the paragraph outlines.

Comment: It is still saying this is incorrect. Would there be another sentence that would also be removed? It is giving me an option to choose more than one.

Comment: You've moved the goal posts. It's cool, but the site is strictly for Q&A; it's not a support forum. Sorry.